# Number of lines from XCode project

Tags: xcode, line-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find out how many lines of code there are in an Xcode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003534/how-to-find-out-how-many-lines-of-code-there-are-in-an-xcode-project)

I was wondering if there is anyway to count the total number of code lines from an XCode project.