# Tool for counting total files,functions and number of lines in iphone application

Tags: ios

I am trying to find total number of files,functions and total number of line code in iOS application.Is there any tool for find this.Is this possible to find ?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005871/number-of-lines-from-xcode-project http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003534/how-to-find-out-how-many-lines-of-code-there-are-in-an-xcode-project

Comment: How can this be off topic? Development is about a lot more than what code to type for what problem. Sometimes it involves analyzing what you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**for line of codes :**

```
find . "(" -name ".m" -or -name ".mm" -or -name "*.cpp" ")" -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l
```

**for number of files :**

```
//you need to write this code
NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *filelist= [filemgr directoryContentsAtPath: yourPath];
int count = [filelist count];
NSLog ("%i",count);
```

**for number of functions :**

```
No tool or code in my knowledge
```

Comment: For number of files just use `find` then pipe the list of files to `| wc -l`.

Answer (score -1):

ls, grep and wc are your friends. ls to count files, grep to count functions and wc to count lines per file.