# why isn't this regex working : find ./ -regex '.*\(m\|h\)$

Tags: regex, macos

Why isn't this regex working?

```
  find ./ -regex '.*\(m\|h\)$
```

I noticed that the following works fine:

```
  find ./ -regex '.*\(m\)$'
```

But when I add the "or a h at the end of the filename" by adding `\|h` it doesn't work.  That is, it should pick up all my `*.m` and `*.h` files, but I am getting nothing back.

I am on Mac OS X.

Comment: Just use `find . -name '*.[mh]' -type f`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

On Mac OS X, you can't use `\|` in a basic regular expression, which is what `find` uses by default.

[re_format man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/re_format.7.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/7/re_format)

> [basic] regular expressions differ in several respects.  | is an ordinary character and  there is no equivalent for its functionality.

The easiest fix in this case is to change `\(m\|h\)` to `[mh]`, e.g.

```
find ./ -regex '.*[mh]$'
```

Or you could add the `-E` option to tell find to use extended regular expressions instead.

```
find -E ./ -regex '.*(m|h)$'
```

Unfortunately `-E` isn't portable.

Also note that if you only want to list files ending in `.m` or `.h`, you have to escape the dot, e.g.

```
find ./ -regex '.*\.[mh]$'
```

If you find this confusing (me too), there's a great reference table that shows which features are supported on which systems.

[Regex Syntax Summary](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/2002/06/regexp.html) [[Google Cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/2002/06/regexp.html)]

Comment: Unless `find` is using a different flavor of regex, the original `\(m\|h\)` is matching `(m|h)` literally, not either an "m" or an "h". While you're solving the question, it seems like you're just providing a way around it and you didn't address the *why*.

Comment: No, according the [man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html), Mac OS/Darwin/BSD find uses basic regular expressions by default.

Comment: @Mikel Right…so the reason the regex in the question didn't work is because it was escaping the characters. Reading comprehension is inversely correlated to reading speed. ;)

Comment: @coreyward: Yes and no.  It's actually trying to match literally `m\|h`.  On Mac OS X, `\(` and `\)` are supported, but `\|` isn't.

Comment: Way too complicated! You don’t need a regex. Globs work fine: `find . -name '*.[mh]' -type f`

Comment: @Mikel: yes, I know this is an old thread.  I thought I would mention that the `-E` should come *before* the path variable.  E.g., `find -E ./ -regex ".*(m|h)$"`

Answer (score 12):

A more efficient solution is to use the `-o` flag:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.m" -o -name "*.h" \)
```

but if you want the regex use:

```
find . -type f -regex ".*\.[mh]$"
```

Comment: `-type f` in the first example was only being applied to `-name "*.h"` (and not `-name "*.m"`) due to precedence.  Fixed.

Comment: Why do you need that weird `\( .. \)`. It works if you chain `-name -o -name ...`

Answer (score 3):

Okay this is a little hacky but if you don't want to wrangle the regex limitations of find on OSX, you can just pipe find's output to grep:

```
find . | grep ".*\(\h\|m\)"
```

Answer (score 1):

What’s wrong with

```
find . -name '*.[mh]' -type f
```

If you want fancy patterns, then use *find2perl* and hack the pattern.