# why isn't this regex working: find ./ -regex '.*[mh]$' | sort | grep --exclude="UnitTests" *

Tags: regex, macos, grep

why isn't this regex working:

```
   find ./ -regex '.*[mh]$' | sort | grep --exclude="UnitTests" *
```

The following works:

```
   find ./ -regex '.*[mh]$' | sort
   find ./ -regex '.*[mh]$' | sort | grep "UnitTests"
```

When I'm adding the "--exclude" (as I want everything but lines with UnitTests in them) I seem to come to grief.

I'm on Mac OSX

Comment: possible duplicate of [why isn't this regex working : find ./ -regex '.*\(m\|h\)$](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905493/why-isnt-this-regex-working-find-regex-m-h)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
find ./ -regex '.*[mh]$' | sort | grep -v "UnitTests"
```

instead. `--exclude` is used when recursing subdirectories, but your `grep` is done based on the pipe (the output) from `find ./ -regex '.*[mh]$' | sort`.