# Know how many lines of code you have in an Xcode project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I've got quite a big project and eventually I finished it. I'm just curious to know how many lines of code there are altogether in my project. I'm using Xcode 3. 
So can you actually find out how many lines of code have been compiled?

Comment: It's not the size of the code that counts, but what you do with it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find out how many lines of code there are in an Xcode project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003534/how-to-find-out-how-many-lines-of-code-there-are-in-an-xcode-project)

Answer (score 68):

Open up Terminal.app, go into your project's root directory, and run this command:

For Swift only:

```
find . \( -iname \*.swift \) -exec wc -l '{}' \+
```

For Obj-C only:

```
find . \( -iname \*.m -o -iname \*.mm -o -iname \*.h \) -exec wc -l '{}' \+
```

For Obj-C + Swift:

```
find . \( -iname \*.m -o -iname \*.mm -o -iname \*.h -o -iname \*.swift \) -exec wc -l '{}' \+
```

For Obj-C + Swift + C + C++:

```
find . \( -iname \*.m -o -iname \*.mm -o -iname \*.c -o -iname \*.cc -o -iname \*.h -o -iname \*.hh -o -iname \*.hpp -o -iname \*.cpp -o -iname \*.swift \) -exec wc -l '{}' \+
```

> Terminal quick tips:
>   ls: list directory contents
>   cd: change directory
>   Press tab to autocomplete
>   Remember to put "\" backslash before spaces
>   I suggest going one folder down from the main project so you get rid of code count from the frameworks

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 34):

Open up Terminal.app, `cd` into your project's root directory, and run this command:

```
find . \( -iname \*.m -o -iname \*.mm -o -iname \*.c -o -iname \*.cc -o -iname \*.h \) -exec wc -l '{}' \+
```

If you other file types you also want to include in your count, then add more `-o \*.ext` clauses.

Comment: Don't forget `'*.hh` and `'*.hpp'` and `'*.cpp'`!

Comment: for some reason this only counts *.h files on OS X

Comment: i needed with out commented lines and blank lines , how can I get this ?

Comment: there is one at the bottom answer

Answer (score 5):

You can use [sloccount](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/) or cloc to do this, they are both compatible with Objective-C code.

I recommend using sloccount, you can get a nice HTML report if you also use Jenkins. The HTML report will enable you to drill down to the different directories and files.

This is a command line for just having an overview of your code, if you are in the root dir of your Xcode project:

```
    sloccount --duplicates --wide YOUR-TARGET-NAME
```

And if you want to generate a report to use in Jenkins, just add the `--details` flag:

```
    sloccount --duplicates --wide --details YOUR-TARGET-NAME > build/sloccount.sc
```

and install the Jenkins plugin for sloccount via Jenkins UI.

You will be able to see examples of such reports in Jenkins in this blog article (disclaimer: I am the author): http://blog.octo.com/en/jenkins-quality-dashboard-ios-development/#step1-1.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: @andrew-barber thanks, I have corrected this and improved my post with a command line example.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to load a copy into Xcode and use "Project Analyzer for Xcode 4".  Search for "Xcode" in the Apple Mac App Store.  I have not used this program but I happened to see it yesterday when I was searching for Xcode related apps in the Mac App Store.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I use a free app called "Xcode analyzer" for this since years. Its probably not as good as "Project Analyzer" but it can count the toc and hey, its free.

Answer (score 3):

A bash script which finds line count of files `WITHOUT COMMENTS AND EMPTY LINES`. The script doesn't count comments which start with `//`. Copy the script to your project folder and run by `sh scriptname.sh`.

For swift change `\( -iname \*.m -o -iname \*.mm -o -iname \*.h \)` to `\( -iname \*.swift \)`

```
# $excluded is a regex for paths to exclude from line counting
excluded="some_dir_name\|some_dir_name2\|lib\|thisfile"

countLines(){
  # $total is the total lines of code counted
  total=0
  # -mindepth exclues the current directory (".")
  for file in `find . -mindepth 1 \( -iname \*.m -o -iname \*.mm -o -iname \*.h \) | grep -v "$excluded"`; do
    # First sed: only count lines of code that are not commented with //
    # Second sed: don't count blank lines
    # $numLines is the lines of code
    numLines=`cat $file | sed '/\/\//d' | sed '/^\s*$/d' | wc -l`

    # To exclude only blank lines and count comment lines, uncomment this:
    #numLines=`cat $file | sed '/^\s*$/d' | wc -l`

    total=$(($total + $numLines))
    echo "  " $numLines $file
  done
  echo "  " $total in total
}

countLines
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about any tools that plug into Xcode directly (why are you still using Xcode 3 when 4.1 is freely available on Lion?), but I find that the command-line [`cloc`](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/) tool works well with Objective-C code.

Comment: Im getting a new MBP next week, so I thought I'll upgrade then ;)

Answer (score 0):

A really nice unix command is xargs.  See the "pipe to xargs below".  For example:

```
find . \( -iname \*.m -o -iname \*.mm -o -iname \*.h -o -iname \*.swift \)  | xargs wc -l
```

Oddly, I'll have to figure out though why this answer comes out a tiny bit lower for me than the answer from @Esqarrouth