# Count total number of lines in an Xcode project

Tags: xcode, rowcount

What is the way to count total number of lines in an Xcode Project? I can see number of lines in an individual file but I need a sum up of all the lines in a project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an app on the App Store called [Xcode Statistics](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/project-statistics-for-xcode/id650764572?l=en&mt=12). (Or something like that). It does what you want.

A word of warning though. The number of lines in a project has little to no relation to the quality or complexity of that project.

Comment: Thanks for that. And on your second point, I know I know. It is just for the fun of it ;)

Comment: Oh and for others the name is: "project statistics for xcode"

Comment: Somebody should invent a way to point to another resource without having to relate on the correct search term. /snark https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/project-statistics-for-xcode/id650764572?l=en&mt=12

Comment: @MatthiasBauch lol! I was on my phone at the time so wasn't able to find the app on the Mac App Store. Lol

Comment: Comments on App Store indicate no Swift support.  Last version update was 5 years ago.

Comment: @DarrellRoot you’re commenting on a question and answer that is 5 years old... ‍♂️

Comment: Yes. Just had this problem and upvoted the answer in 4th place as most helpful. Did not downvote anyone.  Just commented.  We are building a library of questions and answers, but the rapid recent development of Swift hurts answer relevance. Might be a topic for meta.

Comment: Xcode Statistics is out of date and no longer works

Answer (score 55):

A lightweight solution if you're using Homebrew (and a fan of the terminal) is the command-line program 'Cloc' (count lines of code). It breaks down the output for languages used in your project and gives you other useful information.

[Cloc](http://jerodsanto.net/2013/02/cloc-counts-lines-of-code/)

```
$ brew install cloc 
$ cd path/to/project/ 
$ cloc .
```

Comment: `$ brew install cloc`
`$ cd path/to/project/`
`$ cloc .`

Comment: Make sure to exclude Pods if you use Cocoapods!
`$ cloc . --exclude-dir=Pods`

Comment: what about swift packages? How do you skip those?

Comment: Swift Packages are cloned into a separate location - by default, ~/Library/Caches/org.swift.spm.

Answer (score 36):

If you don't want to pay $4.99 for a one time use, and you don't want to bother with HomeBrew.  While it does count the empty lines between your code, you can do this:

1. Open Terminal
2. cd to your Xcode project
3. Execute the following when inside your target project:

`find . -name "*.swift" -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l`

If you want to exclude pods:

```
find . -path ./Pods -prune -o -name "*.swift" -print0 ! -name "/Pods" | xargs -0 wc -l
```

If your project has objective c and swift:

```
find . -type d \( -path ./Pods -o -path ./Vendor \) -prune -o \( -iname \*.m -o -iname \*.mm -o -iname \*.h -o -iname \*.swift \) -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l
```

Comment: Why above commands ask me to access Photos and Contacts?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk, not sure what you mean, can you paste your terminal output? Or any other output?

Answer (score 10):

Check out: [CLOC](http://cloc.sourceforge.net)

> ClOC counts blank lines, comment lines, and physical lines of source
>   code.

To use CLOC (Count Lines Of Code) for count number of lines in a project. Download the the CLOC .pl file and write following line in terminal:

```
perl ./DirectoryWhereClockFileIS/cloc-1.56.pl ./YourDirectoryWhereYourSourcesAre
```

It will show you results like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script to do that :)

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

"""
    Count number of lines of code in a projects 
    directory.

    Credits to https://github.com/0RaMsY0
"""

import os
import argparse

def count_lines(path: str, code_extension: str) -> int:
    FOLDERS = []
    FILES = []
    PATHS = [path]
    TOTAL_LINES = 0
    STOP_LOOP = False

    while STOP_LOOP != True:
        for i in PATHS:
            for _ in os.listdir(i):
                if _.endswith(f".{code_extension}"):
                    FILES.append(f"{i}/{_}")
                else:
                    if os.path.isdir(f"{i}/{_}"):
                        PATHS.append(f"{i}/{_}")
        
        STOP_LOOP = True
    
    for FILE in FILES:
        TOTAL_LINES += len(open(FILE, "r").readlines())
    
    return TOTAL_LINES



if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--path", help="Path to count code numbers")
    parser.add_argument("-ex", "--extension", help="Code extenstion e.g py js ...")
    
    args = parser.parse_args()

    PATH = args.path
    CODE_EXTENSION = args.extension

    TOTAL_LINES = count_lines(PATH, code_extension=CODE_EXTENSION)

    print(TOTAL_LINES)
```

Usage:

you need to pass in two flags one for your project's path and the other is the extension of the source code for example it can be py for python, js for javascript etc...

```bash
python countlines.py -p "/path/to/project" -ex py
```

Warning: Do not add a '.' to the start of the extension or it will not work