# Find size contributed by each external library on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, uikit

I'm trying to reduce my app store binary size and we have lots of external libs that might be contributing to the size of the final ipa. Is there any way to find out how much each external static lib takes up in the final binary (Other than going about removing each one ?) ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

All of this information is contained in the link map, if you have the patience for sifting through it (for large apps, it can be quite large).  The link map has a listing of all the libraries, their object files, and all symbols that were packaged into your app, all in human-readable text.  Normally, projects aren't configured to generate them by default, so you'll have to make a quick project file change.

From within Xcode:

1. Under 'Build Settings' for your target, search for "map"
2. In the results below, under the 'Linking' section, set 'Write Link Map File' to "Yes"
3. Make sure to make note of the full path and file name listed under 'Path to Link Map File'

The next time you build your app you'll get a link map dumped to that file path.  Note that the path is relative to your app's location in the DerivedData folder (usually `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<your-app-name>-<random-string-of-letters-and-numbers>/Build/Intermediates/...`, but YMMV).  Since it's just a text file, you can read it with any text editor.

The contents of the link map are divided into 3 sections, of which 2 will be relevant to what you're looking for:

1. Object Files: this section contains a listing of all of the object files included in your final app, including your own code and that of any third-party libraries you've included.  Importantly, each object file also lists the library where it came from;
2. Sections: this section, not relevant to your question, contains a list of the processor segments and their sections;
3. Symbols: this section contains the raw data that you're interested in: a list of all symbols/methods with their absolute location (i.e. address in the processor's memory map), size, and most important of all, a cross-reference to their containing object module (under the 'File' column).

From this raw data, you have everything you need to do the required size calculation.  From #1, you see that, for every library, there are N possible constituent object modules; from #2, you see that, for every object module, there are M possible symbols, each occupying size S.  For any given library, then, your rough order of size will be something like O(N * M * S).  That's only to give you an indication of the components that would go into your actual calculations, it's not any sort of a useful formula.  To perform the calculation itself, I'm sorry to say that I'm not aware of any existing tools that will do the requisite processing for you, but given that the link map is just a text file, with a little script magic and ingenuity you can  construct a script to do the heavy lifting.

For example, I have a little sample project that links to the following library: https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/LinqToObjectiveC (the sample project itself is from a nice tutorial on ReactiveCocoa, here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/62699/reactivecocoa-tutorial-pt1), and I want to know how much space it occupies.  I've generated a link map, TwitterInstant-LinkMap-normal-x86_64.txt (it runs in the simulator).  In order to find all object modules included by the library, I do this:

```
$ grep -i "libLinqToObjectiveC.a" TwitterInstant-LinkMap-normal-x86_64.txt
```

which gives me this:

```
[  8] /Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TwitterInstant-ecppmzhbawtxkwctokwryodvgkur/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libLinqToObjectiveC.a(LinqToObjectiveC-dummy.o)
[  9] /Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TwitterInstant-ecppmzhbawtxkwctokwryodvgkur/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libLinqToObjectiveC.a(NSArray+LinqExtensions.o)
[ 10] /Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TwitterInstant-ecppmzhbawtxkwctokwryodvgkur/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libLinqToObjectiveC.a(NSDictionary+LinqExtensions.o)
```

The first column contains the cross-references to the symbol table that I need, so I can search for those:

```
$ cat TwitterInstant-LinkMap-normal-x86_64.txt | grep -e "\[  8\]"
```

which gives me:

```
0x100087161 0x0000001B  [  8] literal string: PodsDummy_LinqToObjectiveC
0x1000920B8 0x00000008  [  8] anon
0x100093658 0x00000048  [  8] l_OBJC_METACLASS_RO_$_PodsDummy_LinqToObjectiveC
0x1000936A0 0x00000048  [  8] l_OBJC_CLASS_RO_$_PodsDummy_LinqToObjectiveC
0x10009F0A8 0x00000028  [  8] _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PodsDummy_LinqToObjectiveC
0x10009F0D0 0x00000028  [  8] _OBJC_CLASS_$_PodsDummy_LinqToObjectiveC
```

The second column contains the size of the symbol in question (in hexadecimal), so if I add them all up, I get 0x103, or 259 bytes.

Even better, I can do a bit of stream hacking to whittle it down to the essential elements and do the addition for me:

```
$ cat TwitterInstant-LinkMap-normal-x86_64.txt | grep -e "\[  8\]" | grep -e "0x" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs printf "%d\n" | paste -sd+ - | bc
```

which gives me the number straight up:

```
259
```

Doing the same for `"\[  9\]"` (13016 bytes) and `"\[ 10\]"` (5503 bytes), and adding them to the previous 259 bytes, gives me 18778 bytes.

You can certainly improve upon the stream hacking I've done here to make it a bit more robust (in this implementation, you have to make sure you get the exact number of spaces right and quote the brackets), but you at least get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your awesome answer. I'll try and write something to calculate the contributed sizes.

Comment: Sorry for digging up this topic but this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003534/how-to-find-out-how-many-lines-of-code-there-are-in-an-xcode-project) can also be an alternative for exact counts.

Comment: @Ethenyl, that would only work if you have the actual source code for the third party library in question, which quite often is not the case.

Comment: @fullofsquirrels true, as you pointed it, 3rd party code will always be hard to get metrics from. Depends on the package manager too.

Comment: @SamhanSalahuddin Did you ever write a script to calculate the contributed sizes? I'm looking to do that (for internal & external libs), but it would be great to see a gist or something if it's already been done!

Answer (score 4):

Make a .ipa file of your app and save it in your system.

Then open the terminal and execute the following command:

> unzip -lv /path/to/your/app.ipa

It will return a table of data about your .ipa file. The size column has the compressed size of each file within your .ipa file.

Comment: The question was about static lib size that are linked statically into the binary. Your response only lists files inside .ipa but the binary is 1 file only.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to extract the information you need from this:

symbols -w -noSources YourFileHere

Ref: https://devforums.apple.com/message/926442#926442

IIRC, it isn't going to give you clear summary information on each lib, but you should find that the functions from each library should be clustered together, so with a bit of effort you can calculate the approximate contribution from each lib:

Comment: External link appears to be working again now after being down for awhile (you do need to login though). Was presumably an temporary issue with Apple's forums.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that you set Generate Debug Symbols to NO in your build settings. This can reduce the size of your static library by about 30%.

In case it's part of your concern, a static library is just the relevant .o files archived together plus some bookkeeping. So a 1.7mb static library — even if the code within it is the entire 1.7mb — won't usually add 1.7mb to your product. The usual rules about dead code stripping will apply.

Beyond that you can reduce the built size of your code. The following probably isn't a comprehensive list.

In your target's build settings look for 'Optimization Level'. By switching that to 'Fastest, Smallest -Os' you'll permit the compiler to sacrifice some speed for size.

Make sure you're building for thumb, the more compact ARM code. Assuming you're using LLVM that means making sure you don't have -mno-thumb anywhere in your project settings.

Also consider which architectures you want to build for. Apple doesn't allow submission of an app that supports both ARMv6 and the iPhone 5 screen and have dropped ARMv6 support entirely from the latest Xcode. So there's probably no point including that at this point.

Comment: We decided to use swift. Adds 5 - 8 MB . :(