# The iOS build package is so large, any optimizing strategy

Tags: ios, optimization, build, app-store, ipa

I was wondering if there’s any good approach to shorten the `ipa` package’s  size.

I did setting on `Building Settings - Optimization Level` choose `Fastest, Smallest[-Os]` and `Fastest, Aggressive Optimization [-Ofast]` option for `AdHoc`.

[image: Optimization-setting]

The result is the same. The size is not shorten at all.

The app store’s verifying require submited `ipa` size less than `100M`, or it will warning the size is too big. However, mine is more than ⚠️ `162M`.

Is there any optimizing strategy, thanks for sharing.

Comment: Did you read this? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1795/_index.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722606/what-does-enable-bitcode-do-in-xcode-7

Comment: This could be attributed to large assets within the bundle. Try resizing any images that you may have included in your project to be only as large as they **need** be. No larger.

Comment: how you are getting the ipa? is it drag dropping the the file to itunes from app archive and getting the ipa or by exporting the signed ipa from xcode organizer?

Comment: exporting the signed package

Comment: Check this to determine which file is contributing most to your ipa size..   http://stackoverflow.com/a/39593377/4637057

Answer (score 0):

Awesome!   It is doesn't matter, if the ipa package is really so big, just submit to app store, it isn't rejected by app store for the package size. It usually give a warning, `The size is too big, you need to reduce its size, or do some optimizing`