# Count of third-party code in xcode project

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, code-statistics, xcode-project

How can I get a percent count of third-party code in my Xcode project? It is necessary to find not the number of lines in the "Pods"  directory, but the amount of code described in the "Pods" directory that is used in the main project directory.

For example:

- I have a project with 100 lines of code
- In this project installed Alamofire pod
- One line of 100 lines code is "let method = HTTPMethod.get", that refers to Alamofire pod

The result is: 1% of third-party code usage

Comment: Depending on the size of your project you can comment import of third-party, so for example, "//import Alamofire". Each call of third party function will cause an error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39593377/4637057